# On continuous modifications being indistinguishable for random fields

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Suppose we have a (uncountable) probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Let $X,Y: T \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be random fields on $T=\mathbb{R^d}$, $d>1$ and suppose they are (almost sure) continuous modifications of each other. Modification meaning $\forall t \in T, P(X(t,\omega)=Y(t,\omega))=1$, then does it hold:

i) $X,Y$ are indistinguishable? Indistinguishable meaning $P(X(t,\omega)=Y(t,\omega) \: \forall t \in T)=1$

I think the proof would just be the proof given here for $d=1$ (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/315842/863310) but with $\mathbb{Q}$ replaced by $\mathbb{Q^d}$ and right continuous replaced by continuous?

ii) Furthermore, for $d=1$ we only required right continuity instead of continuity for modifications $X,Y$ to be indistinguishable. so is there an analogue weaker condition in higher dimensions instead of requiring continuity? In particular, would 'continuity' in some direction be enough? It seems like the same proof works by just replacing 'right continuity' with 'continuity in some direction' but I don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: By continuous modification, you mean they both have continuous sample paths and they are modifications of each other?

Comment: @温泽海
Yes, they both (almost surely) have continuous sample paths and are modifications of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Right-continuity with regard to *every* variable $t_1,\ldots,t_d$ is sufficient to conclude.

Indeed by your assumption, the event $A : = \bigcap_{t \in \mathbf{Q}^d}[X_t=Y_t]$ is almost sure. Assume that almost surely, $X$ and $Y$ are right-continuous with regard to every variable $t_1,\ldots,t_d$. Call $B$ the almost-sure corresponding event on which these right-continuity hold.

Then given $\omega \in A \cap B$, the functions $t \mapsto X_t(\omega)$ and $t \mapsto Y_t(\omega)$ coincide $\mathbf{Q}^d$, therefore on $\mathbf{R} \times \mathbf{Q}^{d-1}$ (by right-continuity with regard to $t_1$), therefore on $\mathbf{R}^2 \times \mathbf{Q}^{d-2}$ (by right-continuity with regard to $t_2$),..., and finally on $\mathbf{R}^d$.

Remark: continuity in only one direction is not sufficient. For example, assume that $X_t$ and $Y_t$ depends only on $t_1$ without any other regularity assumption. Although you have continuity with regards to every other variable $t_2,\ldots,t_d$, you cannot derive indistinguability.